# How can I set up the scss/sass file in django?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, sass

Im working on a personal project and im using django.
In this project I like to use scss/sass style file, but I dont know how to install and set up in my Django project.
Any help will be appreciated
Thank u!

Answer (score 2):

In order to work with scss or sass in django project

#### Step 1:

Install sass/scss in your local machine either npm or Homebrew (i prefer npm)

[sass installation guide](https://sass-lang.com/install)

#### Step 2:

After installation, you need to compile your sass/scss to css file.
For that, run the command (in cmd for windows)

```
sass [your scss file location] [where your css file needs to be stored]
```

For example..

```
sass source/stylesheets/index.scss build/stylesheets/index.css
```

If you are using django, then you must be using **static** folder in your project, in that case you should go with this command

```
sass static/scss/index.scss static/css/index.css
```

#### Step 3:

The above command needs to be executed every single time when a change occurs in scss file..
Inorder to get rid of that, use a **--watch** command.

```
sass --watch static/scss/index.scss static/css/index.css
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways to do this. You can work with scss/sass files with Python or with NPM. If you do not want to mess with node.js I would recommend to use python way (install *django-sass-processor*):

Check out this clear manual - [How to Easily Use SASS/SCSS with Django](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-easily-use-sass-scss-with-django/) from [webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210225201318/https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-easily-use-sass-scss-with-django/) or [django-sass-processor](https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor).

Basically run install:

```bash
pip install libsass django-compressor django-sass-processor
```

Add to configuration file:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'sass_processor',
    ...
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
```

Using Django-sass-processor in Templates:

Inside of your template, load in django-sass’s library tags and use {% sass_src %} instead of {% static %} to load your SCSS/SASS stylesheet.

```html
{% load sass_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="{% sass_src 'path/to/file.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Django Sass</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>This template's stylesheet was written SASS/SCSS</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This link is obsolete as of now

Comment: Which link is obsolete?